# Android Kitkat compatibility issue

Tags: ionic-framework, build, compatibility, android-4.4-kitkat

I'm using ionic v1 for a project and I have some compatibility issues.
I must deliver on Android KitKat OS (on a tablet) an application and many things don't work on KK but work on browsers on my PC.

For example https://awe.media/static/drawimage/minimal.html I've simply tried to use this code to do some tests (it works on my PC's browsers).

- I adapted the code to ionic v1 to make it work on my PC's browser

- Once it works I build the APK and install the APK on my emulator KK + KK real device and it doesn't work anymore.

PS: I've tried with and without Crosswalk

I come to think that maybe it's a build issue.

Any idea?

Thanks for reading.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need to check in yourprojectname\platforms\android\AndroidManifest.xml

First check your android:minSdkVersion and android:targetSdkVersion:

You can replace it with this line if its diffrent from this:

```
<uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="16" android:targetSdkVersion="25" />
```